# HP Pavillion dv9500 power on black screen

Tags: boot, laptop, hp-pavilion

Having some problems with my HP Pavillion laptop.

I've removed the battery, plugged in the power cable, and press the power button. The fans start up, and power light and the row of lights for the quick-media controls above the keyboard all come on blue. The screen lights up but stays blank black.

Pressing any of the lit-up media buttons gives a short high pitched beep. Otherwise, I can't get any activity of any sort out of it.

Holding escape during boot doesn't have any effect.

The blue light on the SD slot lights up for the first few seconds of booting then goes off. After ~10 seconds the fans spin down, harddisk goes quiet.

Any suggestions on what to try next please?

Answer (score 0):

http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c01997899

are you able to boot to anything? on the bottom right does it say press (key) to boot to (cd, dvd) ?

if so boot into a windows install disk then click repair my computer then boot up repair.

if you do not have a boot disk you can do a Google search for: Windows 7 home premium 64 bit SP1 legal ISO download. of course change this to your specs. you can burn this ISO image to a DVD 4.7 gig or an 8 gig flash drive, tools like YUMI multiboot can help as well.

boot into BIOS and reset exit and save.

if all else fails boot into a copy of Linux, Ubuntu and backup anything you need and erase all partitions in gparted then boot into a copy of dban and run a quick erase then install windows...

Comment: OP here - there is nothing on the screen but it has power (the screen lights up, but black).

Comment: oooh... well then, does the screen turn on and at least show the color black and not a off monitor?

Comment: Umm not sure what you mean to distinguish between the two. There's power to the screen (as in you can see it 'light up' in a dark room) but it's all black.

Don't think I could honestly say whether it is displaying black or if it not displaying anything?

Comment: okay, i was just asking if it actually turned on.

Comment: check here: http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c01997899